# How can i remove this class color in the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

i was trying to create custom navigation bar. but i am facing a problem when i give a color to navigation bar than there is another ash color is coming. Here what i try

```
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 15, width: self.view.frame.size.width,height: 50))

        navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use barTintColor instead of backgroundColor

```
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 15, width: self.view.frame.size.width,height: 50))
navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

Comment: Why there is a black line in the middle of navigation bar

Comment: Do you added something more? If it is only the navBar should work